# Function with pointer as parameter - what does the function expect by calling?

Tags: c++, pointers

I saw this example:

```
void pass_by_value(int* p)
{
//Allocate memory for int and store the address in p
p = new int;
}

void pass_by_reference(int*& p)
{
p = new int;
}

int main()
{
int* p1 = NULL;
int* p2 = NULL;

pass_by_value(p1); //p1 will still be NULL after this call
pass_by_reference(p2); //p2 's value is changed to point to the newly allocate memory

return 0;
}
```

if i call the function pass-by-value, shouldnt it expect something like "&p" instead of p?

Comment: You saw C++ example, not C one.

Comment: `shouldnt it expect something like "&p" instead of p?` Yes, thats why `p1` is still null after the call.

Comment: If a function expects `int*` and `p` is `int*` then you should give it `p`. `&p` would be an `int**`. It's not clear to me what you are asking.

Comment: But I dont get it, isnt it that u should give the adress to the function when it expects a pointer? cuz the pointer points to the adress I guess?

Answer (score 1):

The pass-by-value is messed up anyway, the value passed to the function would be lost when the call completes and the memory would leak. It's legal code, it's just useless. If not using references or function return value the function would need to take a pointer-to-pointer (really, the compiler is likely to produce the same code for both the pointer-to-pointer and reference-to-pointer cases - barring inlining - it's just a bit cleaner to use the reference):

```
void foo(int ** p)
{
    *p = new int;
}

int main()
{
    int * p = nullptr;
    foo(&p);
    delete p;
}
```